# Как изменить список с поиском используя Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть список, созданный по инструкции https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Проблема в том, что когда вводишь данные, которых нет в списке, то выдача пустая. Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе несуществующих данных в выдаче было написано, что ничего не найдено?

Я в JS не разбираюсь толком, надеюсь на поддержку по данному вопросу.

```js
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
    background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png'); /* Add a search icon to input */
    background-position: 10px 12px; /* Position the search icon */
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Do not repeat the icon image */
    width: 100%; /* Full-width */
    font-size: 16px; /* Increase font-size */
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px; /* Add some padding */
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a grey border */
    margin-bottom: 12px; /* Add some space below the input */
}

#myUL {
    /* Remove default list styling */
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
    border: 1px solid #ddd; /* Add a border to all links */
    margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
    background-color: #f6f6f6; /* Grey background color */
    padding: 12px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove default text underline */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase the font-size */
    color: black; /* Add a black text color */
    display: block; /* Make it into a block element to fill the whole list */
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
    background-color: #eee; /* Add a hover effect to all links, except for headers */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто:

Создал один блок списка или же вне него, это особо не важно со значением `No Results` и `id="noResult"`, и по умолчанию он будет у нас скрытым `display:none`.

Логика дополненного скрипта тоже очень проста:

- Предположим что изначально список у нас пустой, создаем внутри переменную `empty=true`. Также не забываем отобрать сам элемент No Results чтобы обращаться к нему
- Вводим значение в поисковик: Пробегаемся по списку, и в случае если попадеться хоть какой нибудь элемент который отобразиться то сразу наша переменная `empty` становиться `false`, ведь логично что список уже не пустой.
- После этой операции создаем условие:

  - Если список пустой: `if (empty)` то делаем видимым наш отобраный заранее блок `noResult`
  - Иначе скрываем

Вот как это выглядит в нашем коде внизу:

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Объявляем переменные
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, empty, noResult;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');


  // Изначально подразумеваем что список у нас пустой
  empty = true;
  // Отбираем элемент NoResult
  noResult = document.getElementById("noResult");
  // Цикл по всем элементам списка, и скрываем те блоки которые не соответствуют запросу введенному в поиск.
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "block";
      empty = false; // Если найден хотя бы 1 элемент 
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  if (empty) {
    noResult.style.display = "block"; // Если пустой список
  } else {
    noResult.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* Скрываем наш блок */
#noResult {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">

<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>

  <li id="noResult"><a href="#">No results</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

например, добавить после списка div#notfound

```
<div id="notfound">Ничего не найдено</div>
```

css:

```
div#notfound{
    display:none;
}
```

js:

```
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    //добавляем счетчик найденного
    found=0;
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    notfound=document.getElementById("notfound");
    notfound.style.display="none";//скроем если при предыдущем цикле блок был показан

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            found++;
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }
    if(found==0){
        //если ничего не найдено покажем блок "Ничего не найдено"
        document.getElementById("notfound").style.display="block";
    }
}
```